# ¿Cómo actualizo los datos de un footer de un ListView que contiene una suma de todas las filas del ListView al modificar los elementos del mismo?

Tags: android, listview

Me explico ya que mi pregunta puede resultar un poco confusa. Estoy realizando un carro de compras en Android Studio, la aplicación va añadiendo productos a un `ArrayList` el cual utilizo para mostrar los elementos en un `ListView`. En el fragmento del carro de la Compra donde tengo el `Listview`, para cada producto en el carro he añadido dos botones para modificar la cantidad de cada producto, y un icono para eliminar el producto del Listado.

Cuando el fragmento carga la primera vez, el total me aparece correctamente, en el momento que actualizo el carro, no encuentro la forma de insertar el nuevo total en el footer definido del `ListView`. Os dejo mi código por si alguien me puede ayudar.

Fragment carro:

```
public class CarroCompra extends Fragment {

private ListView vistaListaCarro;
private AdaptadorCarrito adapter;

public CarroCompra() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_carro_compra, container, false );
    vistaListaCarro=(ListView)view.findViewById( R.id.listaPantallaCarro );
    //Añadimos header y footer al listview
    LayoutInflater inflador = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_carro, vistaListaCarro,
            false);
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_carro, vistaListaCarro,
            false);
    vistaListaCarro.addHeaderView( header,null,false );
    vistaListaCarro.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
    ArrayList <ProductoCarro> listaCarro=((MainActivity)getActivity()).productosCarro;


    //instanciamos el adaptador
    adapter=new AdaptadorCarrito(  getContext(),listaCarro);
    //le añadimos los datos al listview
    vistaListaCarro.setAdapter( adapter );

    // Calculamos total pedido
    //Creamos la variable que sumara el total de importes de la lista
    double totalPedido=0.0;

    //Creamos un bucle que recorre la lista sumando los totales
    for(int i = 0; i<listaCarro.size();i++){
        //calculamos el precio total de producto en esa fila
        String totalFilaActual=adapter.getItem( i ).precioTotalCalculado( adapter.getItem( i ).getPrecio(),adapter.getItem( i ).cantidad );
        double totalFila2=Double.parseDouble( totalFilaActual );
        //En un double vamos acumulando los valores
        totalPedido=totalPedido+totalFila2;
    }

    //añadimos el importe en el contenedor correspondiente
    final TextView PVPPedido=(TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.total );
   PVPPedido.setText( Double.toString( totalPedido )+" €");


    Button btnDatos=(Button)view.findViewById( R.id.btnContinuarPago );
    btnDatos.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //extraemos el valor
            Bundle bundle= new Bundle(  );
            bundle.putString("total pedido", PVPPedido.getText().toString());
            DatosCompra rellenaDatos=new DatosCompra();
            rellenaDatos.setArguments( bundle );
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.contenedor,rellenaDatos ).addToBackStack( null ).commit();
        }
    } );
    return view;
    }

}
```

Adaptador Listview:

```
public class AdaptadorCarrito extends ArrayAdapter<ProductoCarro> {
public AdaptadorCarrito(Context context, ArrayList<ProductoCarro> 
productosCarrito) {
   // Toast.makeText( getContext(),"total de elementos pasados en el 
array:"+productosCarrito.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    super(context, 0, productosCarrito);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Extraemos el producto actual
    final ProductoCarro productoActual = getItem(position);

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = 
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.plantilla_lista_carro, 
parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView nombreProductoCarro = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombrePantallaCarro);
    TextView precioProductoCarro = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.precioPantallaCarro);
    final EditText cantidadProductoCarro=(EditText) 
convertView.findViewById( R.id.cantidadPantallaCarro );
    final ImageView imagenProductoCarro=(ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById( R.id.imagenPantallaCarro );
    final TextView precioTotalProducto=(TextView)convertView.findViewById( 
R.id.precioFinalProductoPantallaCarro );
    final TextView precioFinal=(TextView)convertView.findViewById( 
R.id.total );


    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    nombreProductoCarro.setText(productoActual.getNombre());
    precioProductoCarro.setText( productoActual.getPrecio()+" €" );
    cantidadProductoCarro.setText( productoActual.getCantidad() );



    Glide
            .with(getContext())
            .load( Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.toni.app_the_object_home/drawable/"+productoActual.getImagen() ))
            .asBitmap()
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imagenProductoCarro) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable
                            = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getContext().getResources(), resource);
                    drawable.setCircular(false);
                    imagenProductoCarro.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                }
            });

    //Calculamos el precio total de cada producto en función de las cantidades seleccionadas
    String PVPtotal=modificaTotalProducto( productoActual.getPrecio(),productoActual.getCantidad() );
    precioTotalProducto.setText( PVPtotal+" €" );

    //Assignamos funcionalidad a los botones de la celda
    Button btnMas=(Button)convertView.findViewById( R.id.btnMasPantallaCarro );
    btnMas.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //extraemos el valor actual en el contenedor
            String 
cantidadActual=cantidadProductoCarro.getText().toString();
            //variable auxiliar para guardar el calculo de la nueva cantidad
            int auxi=0;
            //añadimos una unidad a la cantidad actual
            auxi=Integer.parseInt( cantidadActual )+1;
            //añadimos el valor de la nueva cantidad al conentendor de texto
            cantidadProductoCarro.setText( Integer.toString( auxi ) );
            //llamamos al metodo que modifica el precio final, le pasamos el precio y la cantidad modificada que hay en el contenedor
            String newPVP=modificaTotalProducto( 
productoActual.getPrecio(),cantidadProductoCarro.getText().toString() );
            //añadimos el nuevo precio
            precioTotalProducto.setText( newPVP+" €" );
            //lo almacenamos tambien en el ArrayList para que quede actualizado
            productoActual.setCantidad( Integer.toString( auxi ) );
            // Calculamos total pedido
            Toast.makeText( getContext(),"totalNuevo"+totalPedido(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
//le añado el nuevo valor
precioFinal.setText(totalPedido());



        }
    } );
    Button btnMenos=(Button)convertView.findViewById( R.id.btnMenosPantallaCarro );
    btnMenos.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //extraemos la cantidad que hay actualmente en el contenedor
            String 
cantidadActual=cantidadProductoCarro.getText().toString();
            //variable auxiliar para el cálculo de la nueva cantidad
            int auxi=0;
            //restamos una unidad a la cantidad en carro
            auxi=Integer.parseInt( cantidadActual )-1;
            productoActual.setCantidad( Integer.toString( auxi ) );
            //si la cantidad resultante es superior a 0

            if(auxi>0){
                //modificamos la cantidad de producto en el contenedor
                cantidadProductoCarro.setText( Integer.toString( auxi ) );
                //llamamos al método para el cálculo del precio total
                String newPVP=modificaTotalProducto( 
productoActual.getPrecio(),cantidadProductoCarro.getText().toString() );
                //lo añadimos
                precioTotalProducto.setText( newPVP+" €" );
                //lo almacenamos tambien en el ArrayList para que quede actualizado
                productoActual.setCantidad( Integer.toString( auxi ) );
                Toast.makeText( 
getContext(),"totalNuevo"+totalPedido(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


            } else{
                //advertencia al usuario
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText( getContext(),"El número mínimo de productos es 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
                toast.show();
            }

        }
    } );
    //Funcionalidad botón eliminar productos de Lista
    ImageView borrarProducto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById( R.id.borrarPantallaCarro );
    borrarProducto.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //eliminamos la fila sobre la que actuamos
            remove( productoActual );
            Toast.makeText( 
getContext(),"totalNuevo"+totalPedido(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


        }
    } );

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;


}

  public String modificaTotalProducto (String precio, String cantidad) {
    String PVPtotal;
    //Calculamos el precio del producto según su cantidad
    //variable numerica para los calculos
    double auxiliar = 0.0;
    //multiplicamos cantidad x precio
    auxiliar = ( Double.parseDouble( precio ) ) * ( Double.parseDouble( cantidad ) );
    //limitamos el número de decimales de salida a 2
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( auxiliar );
    bd = bd.setScale( 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP );
    PVPtotal = Double.toString( bd.doubleValue( ) );
    return PVPtotal;

}
  public String totalPedido () {
    ArrayList <ProductoCarro> listaCarro=((MainActivity)getContext()).productosCarro;


    // Calculamos total pedido
    //Creamos la variable que sumara el total de importes de la lista
    double totalPedido = 0.0;

    //Creamos un bucle que recorre la lista sumando los totales
    for (int i = 0; i < listaCarro.size(); i++) {
        //calculamos el precio total de producto en esa fila
        String totalFilaActual = this.getItem(i).precioTotalCalculado(this.getItem(i).getPrecio(), this.getItem(i).cantidad);
        double totalFila2 = Double.parseDouble(totalFilaActual);
        //En un double vamos acumulando los valores
        totalPedido = totalPedido + totalFila2;
    }
    //devolvemos el total del pedido

    return Double.toString(totalPedido) + " €";
}
```

}

Clase Producto:

```
public class ProductoCarro {
    String nombre;
    String cantidad;
    String precio;
    String imagen;
    double precioTotal;
    public ProductoCarro() {
    }

    public ProductoCarro(String nombre, String cantidad, String precio,String imagen) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.imagen=imagen;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(String cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public String getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(String precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public double getPrecioTotal() {
        return precioTotal;
    }

    public void setPrecioTotal(double precioTotal) {
        this.precioTotal = precioTotal;
    }

    public String precioTotalCalculado (String precio, String Cantidad){
        String PVPtotal;
        //Calculamos el precio del producto según su cantidad
        //variable numerica para los calculos
        double auxiliar=0.0;
        //multiplicamos cantidad x precio
        auxiliar=(Double.parseDouble( precio))*(Double.parseDouble( cantidad ));
        //limitamos el número de decimales de salida a 2
        BigDecimal bd= new BigDecimal( auxiliar );
        bd=bd.setScale( 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP );
        PVPtotal=Double.toString( bd.doubleValue() );
        return PVPtotal;
    }
}
```

Layout Footer:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAmarillo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/totalPedidoCliente"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalPedidoCliente"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text="TOTAL PEDIDO"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/totalPedidoCliente"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnContinuarPago"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAmarillo"
    android:text="CONTINUAR"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/totalPedidoCliente" />
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería mucho, si he cometido algún error al realizar la pregunta, pido disculpas, es mi primera vez.

[image: Imagen carro]

Error LogCat:
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                        at com.example.toni.app_the_object_home.AdaptadorCarrito$2.onClick(AdaptadorCarrito.java:106)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

En el adaptador instancio al textview del footer:
final TextView precioFinal=(TextView)convertView.findViewById( R.id.total );

Comment: Corrigeme si entendi mal. En el footer hay un TextView que necesitas actualizar siempre que se agregue/elimine/edite la cantidad de algún producto?

Comment: Puedes mostrar una captura de pantalla?

Comment: Correcto eso es!

Comment: Hola david, acabo de poner una captura del carro para que podáis ver con más detalle lo que quiero hacer, como podéis ver en la fila correspondiente del Listview se actualiza la cantidad total correspondiente a cada producto, pero no consigo actualizar el total de todo lo que haya en el carro.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la instancia de la variable `footer` y busca la referencia del `TextView` (o el tipo de View que utilizas para el contador) utilizando el metodo `findViewById()`. Por ejemplo:

```
TextView cantidadTextView = footer.findViewById(R.id.id_contador);
cantidadTextView.setText("125");
```

Comment: Hola Einer, esta forma que me indicas ya la intenté hacer pero la aplicación se me cierra y me da error. Supongo que se trata de un error al intentar acceder a una instancia del fragmento desde el adaptador. En el adaptador instnacio el TextView del footer, y en el Listener del botón correspondiente intento insertar el nuevo valor del total, pero siempre da error!

Comment: Le pusiste el id correspondiente a tu TextView?

Comment: Si le puse su id, que en el footer definí como ''total''. luego en el adaptador lo instancio, pero cuando quiero modificar el valor desde la clase Adaptador me da error. Por ver si era error del método que me actualiza el valor de los totales probé a asignarle cualquier valor, pero me provoca el mismo error.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el layout del footer por favor

Comment: Lo acabo de poner, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bueno. Necesito el error que te lanza en la consola o logcat. Si puedes también agrega como estas llamando al textview contador

Comment: Lo acabo de incluir, también he editado el código del adaptador para que puedas ver lo que estoy haciendo para insertar el nuevo valor (en el Listener del btnMas), que anteriormente lo tenia con un toast para comprobar que la función iba correctamente. Gracias!